# i dont know how to fix this error: TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

Tags: python, pygame

i keep having this error and i dont know how to fix it:
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

i am trying to build like a game of tag with 2 players on one screen and i need the window to show who is 'it'

here is my code:

```
import pygame as pyg
import pygame.gfxdraw
import time


# Screen
pygame.init()
screen = pyg.display.set_mode((1280, 720), pygame.RESIZABLE)
width,height= screen.get_size()
pygame_icon = pyg.image.load('icon.png')
pyg.display.set_icon(pygame_icon)
pyg.display.set_caption("taggy")
clock = pyg.time.Clock()

black = (0,0,0)
background = black


tikker = 0
PlayerNames = ['Player 1', 'Player 2']
test_font = pyg.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 50)
text = pyg.surface, test_font.render(PlayerNames[0], True, black)

while True:
    for event in pyg.event.get():
        if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
            quit()

    # Code
    screen.fill((background))
    screen.blit(screen, text, (width/2), 50)


    pyg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?
i use vscode and python 3.9.9

Thanks for your time!
:]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Function blit request mandatory items: pygame.suface and position so something like this: `screen.blit(picture, (x, y))`. You don't need to enter the screen because it is already in the command. The program thinks that screen is your image and the text is position. So you need just delete the screen from the function, so replace `screen.blit(screen, text, (width/2), 50)`to `screen.blit( text, (width/2), 50)` I hope it helpled.
Full good code:

```
import pygame as pyg
import pygame.gfxdraw
import time
import sys


# Screen
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pyg.display.set_mode((1280, 720), pygame.RESIZABLE)
width,height= screen.get_size()
pyg.display.set_caption("taggy")
clock = pyg.time.Clock()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
background = black


tikker = 0
PlayerNames = ['Player 1', 'Player 2']
test_font = pyg.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 50)
text = test_font.render(PlayerNames[0], True, white)

while True:
    for event in pyg.event.get():
        if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Code
    screen.fill((background))
    screen.blit(text, (800, 600))


    pyg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I edited cordinates of text a little bit you may will need to change it. If you will use width and height as cordinates the text will go out of screen.

Comment: That doesnt help, it says 'argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not tuple' but anyways, thanks for your time, i will experiment with other stuff and try to fix it :). Have a good one!

Comment: @olivier Hi I got it working for me. Now I will edit my answer with good code :)

Comment: YESSSS thank u so much :D